# Make PriceBookEntry object read only or private?

Tags: permission-sets, owd

Only Owner/Creator should be able to edit Pricebook Entry record
Other users should be have read only access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't change SFDC's default sharing setting for PriceBookEntry. It's a profile permission which works as 'all or nothing'.

The only alternative I see is to create a validation rule, comparing the Owner/Creator with the current User. If they don't match, raise a validation error.